# C - segfault when using strcmp()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, strcmp

I am getting a segfault when using strcmp(). I have tried debugging using gdb and when I run it (without arguments) I get a segfault. When I backtrace, it indicates the segfault is at line 20, but I can't figure out why it's segfaulting. The strcmp() statement is on line 20. I will include lines 0-21 in my post, but can add more if necessary.

The segfault statements when I use the `run` command are as follows:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../stcmp.S:213
213 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: No such file or directory.
```

So then I do a `backtrace` and get this:

```
#0 __strcmp_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:213
#1 0x0000000000400aa6 in main (c=1, v=0x7fffffffead8) at myls.c:20
```

Here is my code from lines 0-21:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main(int c, char *v[])
{
    DIR *directory = NULL;
    strut direct *dir_pointer = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    char cwd[1024];

    if(strcmp(v[1], "-i") == 0){ //line 20, where the segfault happens
        ...
```

any tips/help appreciated.

Comment: "when I run it (without arguments) " - Huh??? you had *better* provide at least one argument, or per the standard `v[1]` is NULL; `strcmp` doesn't play well with `NULL`, for *either* of its arguments.

Comment: @WhozCraig some background on this: I am writing my own ls program that mimics the unix `ls` command. When I run it with `./myls`, that is c=1 correct? And when I run it with `./myls -l` that is c = 2? and the `-l` = v[1]?

Comment: I strongly advise you carefully [read the q&a at the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean) provided by Kons below. It answers that question, and much, *much* more.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling without arguments (c = 1) and accessing the first argument given to the program (as if c was 2)..

I suggest you to read this answer

[What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: What does this have to do with the "strcmp.S" not begin found? As the error is "No such file or directory."

Answer (score 0):

You're either not passing arguments to the program, or it segfaults directly after the `if` statement. The strcmp works.

Edit: Just realized you're NOT passing it without arguments. You're referencing `v[1]` when there is no `v[1]`

Comment: But I have an elif statement that says `else if(c<2){`, should I still be getting a segfault?

Comment: Yes, because you are evaluating `v[1]` first

Comment: So should I have the `if(c<2)` be the first statement? Would this fix it?

Comment: yes, or you could do `c>=2 && strcmp(v[1], "-i") == 0`

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and now I don't get a segfault when running it with `./myls` (no arguments) and `./myls -l`, but I am getting a seg fault when trying to run it with `./myls -i`. My if/else statements are configured as `if(c>=2 && strcmp(v[1], "-i") == 0){`, `else if(c>=2 && strcmp(v[1], "-l") == 0){` and `else{ //ls without arguments area`. Any reason why?

Comment: I don't know. What comes after the `if` condition?

Comment: A bunch of stuff to print my files/directories in `ls -i` format.

Comment: Comment that out and replace it with `printf("It works")`

Comment: commented it out and it's printing "it works".... Guess I have some more fixing to do haha